# NUnit not running generic TestFixture

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I facing strange behavior in Nunit with Generic TestFixture. I am using command line to create test project `dotnet new nunit` and copy pasted these code from NUnit's wiki:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ArrayList))]
[TestFixture(typeof(List<int>))]
public class IList_Tests<TList> where TList : IList, new()
{
  private IList list;

  [SetUp]
  public void CreateList()
  {
    this.list = new TList();
  }

  [Test]
  public void CanAddToList()
  {
    list.Add(1); list.Add(2); list.Add(3);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, list.Count);
  }
}
```

Here is .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NetCoreEFCore3API\NetCoreEFCore3API.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I click `Run All Tests` on top of class and here is result. There are no test listed and run regardless of there is one `CanAddToList` test method. It working fine in case there is no **Generic** for **TestFixture**.

[image: generic testfixture does not listed and run]

**Note**
`dotnet test` working fine for both case generic and non-generic.

Please give me some advise to address this problem. I current use .Netcore and VS Code.

Comment: There is recently created ticket for that: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3722

Comment: Oh, thanks. I left a comment on that issue also.